# Weak Hilbert Nullstellensatz to show the bijection $Z(I)\overset{\simeq}{→} \left\{\text{maximal ideals in }A/I\right\}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

> Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field. Let $I \subset A :=
> k[x_1, \ldots , x_n]$ be an ideal. We denote by
>   $$Z(I) = \{a \in k^n \mid f(a) = 0, \text{ for all } f \in I\}$$
>   the zero set of $I$.
>   Show that we have a bijection
>   $Z(I)\overset{\simeq}{\to} \{\text{maximal ideals in } A/I\}$, $(a_1, \ldots , a_n) \mapsto (\bar{x_1}−a_1, \ldots , \bar{x_n}−a_n)$.
>   In particular, $Z(I) \neq \varnothing \Longleftrightarrow I \neq (1)$.

I have this question in my textbook. I know that I need to use the weak Hilbert Nullstellensatz to prove the surjectivity.But I am unable to proceed the proof. Can anyone help me? Thank you in advance !

Comment: I am sorry, my typos, it should be $\neq$ and I fixed it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Showing that ideals of the form $(x_1-\lambda_1,...,x_n-\lambda_n)$ are maximal is easy (Consider the quotient). Conversely let $\mathfrak{m}$ be a maximal ideal in $B=A/I$. Consider the natural projection $\pi :B \rightarrow B/\mathfrak{m}$. $\mathfrak{m}$ is maximal so $B/\mathfrak{m}$ is a field and it is clearly finitely generated aus a $k$-algebra. Thus by Hilbertsnullstellensatz $B/\mathfrak{m}$ is a finite field extension of $k$. But $k$ is algebraically closed, hence $B/\mathfrak{m}=k$. Denote by $\lambda_i \in k$ the images of $x_i$ under $\pi$. Then we have $x_i-\lambda_i \in ker(\pi)= \mathfrak{m}$. Since the ideal $(x_1-\lambda_1,...,x_n-\lambda_n)$ is maximal we conclude that $\mathfrak{m}=(x_1-\lambda_1,...,x_n-\lambda_n)$.

Remark: For better readability i dropped the bars for the residue classes, so strictly speaking one would have to replace every $x_i$ with $\bar{x_i}$ and similarly for the $\lambda_i$'s.

Comment: How can I show the map is an isomorphism

Comment: Which map do you mean? For the map $(\lambda_1,...,\lambda_n)\rightarrow (x_1-\lambda_1,...,x_n-\lambda_n)$: Showing surjectivity is equivalent to showing that every maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$ is of the form $(x_1-\lambda_1,...x_n-\lambda_n)$. This is exactly what i did. Injectivity is obvious. Also this is only a bijection not an isomorphism...